# php apache - reverse proxy double slash

Tags: php, apache

I have problem with leading double double slash when I use apache reverse proxy.
($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] always starts with //, except when I access directly root.

Configuration

```
ProxyPass /admin/ http://admin.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /admin/ http://admin.example.com/

or

<Location /admin>
   ProxyPass http://admin.example.com/
   ProxyPassReverse http://admin.example.com/
</Location>
```

I've tried all possible combinations like

- ProxyPass /admin http://admin.example.com
- ProxyPass /admin http://admin.example.com/
- ProxyPass /admin/ http://admin.example.com

but no luck. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after more experimenting, this works:

```
<Location /admin>
    ProxyPass http://admin.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse http://admin.example.com
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the same problem. I don't have direct access so will pass this on to the server admin. Thanks again!